# Cannot connect to SQLServer database in Java application

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I have connecting to my database in a JSF web application that I am trying to develop.
Using Windows 7, NetBeans 6.9.1, SQLServer 2008, Glassfish 3.3.

I am using the **sqljdbc4.jar** driver that I copied from my XP system where I have successfully connected to SQLServer 2005.

I have verified that SQLServer 2008 is running on my system and I can connect to the database through SQL Server Management Studio using the username and password that I am trying to use in the application.  The SQL Server Configuration Manager shows the IP connection port is 1433.  So I think my database is set up properly.

I think I am doing things correctly, but I just can't connect to the database.
Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this is failing and what I can check?

Thanks.

Here is my connection code:

```
public void connectDB()
{
    try
    {
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=ROVRDEV;user=rovrdevuser;password=rovrdevuser";
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        System.out.println("Database connection = "+con );
    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println( "Error connecting to database.  Error: "+e.getMessage() );
    }

}
```

When I attempt to run this, I get the following exception in the server log:

```
SEVERE: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:170)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1049)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:833)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:716)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:841)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:207)
    at rmsbackoffice.SessionBean1.connectDB(SessionBean1.java:130)
    at rmsbackoffice.SessionBean1.doInit(SessionBean1.java:107)
    at rmsbackoffice.SessionBean1.beforePhase(SessionBean1.java:88)
    at rmsbackoffice.org$jboss$weld$bean-web-ManagedBean-class_rmsbackoffice$SessionBean1_$$_WeldClientProxy.beforePhase(org$jboss$weld$bean-web-ManagedBean-class_rmsbackoffice$SessionBean1_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:43)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:56)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.notifyPhaseListeners(UIViewRoot.java:1050)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.notifyBefore(UIViewRoot.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeBegin(UIViewRoot.java:959)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1754)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:401)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.
```

Check your SQL Server setting allow accept TCP/IP connections. Enable TCP/IP and restart SQL Server. Then test your code again.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That was it, I checked for the other entries in the Config Mgr, but the network entry was not enabled.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Enterprise Manager go to Properties->Connections and check "Allow remote connections to this server." Also make sure port 1433 isn't being blocked in Windows Firewall. Finally, I'd stop using the Microsoft JDBC jar. I had much better luck with [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried to change Hostname with IP

```
"jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=ROVRDEV;user=rovrdevuser;password=rovrdevuser";
```

become

```
"jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=ROVRDEV;user=rovrdevuser;password=rovrdevuser";
```

maybe just because this one ->

[image]

Answer (score 1):

instanceName is missing in your connection string.

If your SQL server instance name is "SQL2005" then it should be like .....

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;instanceName=SQL2005;databaseName=ROVRDEV","rovrdevuser","rovrdevuser");
```

Answer (score 0):

also check the Sql Server Browser running on not
service - > sql server browser ->start