# Cannot connect to sql server database with netbeans

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans, tcp

I'm making a CRUD application for a local SQL Server database using Netbeans. When I try to create connection to database i'm getting an error:

> The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed.
>   Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties,
>   check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and
>   accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is
>   blocking TCP connections to the port.

[image: Screenshot of a problem]

I'm getting this error, though, I've already enabled TCP/IP for my entry in SQL Server Configuration Manager and I don't use firewall.
[image: Configuration Manager]

Tried everything from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8346092/cannot-connect-to-sqlserver-database-in-java-application), didn't help.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you enable [Login Auditing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6769173/950462) in SQL Server Management Studio and find the relevant part of the [error log](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187109(v=sql.90).aspx)?

Comment: This might help in diagnosing the error: try if you are able to connect using other java based software like `dbVisualizer`. Download `tcpview`and check if port 1433 is open.

Comment: Opened logs, there's no any failed logins

Comment: I don't see port 1433 in tcpview, does it mean that this port is free?
dbVisualizer also can't connect to my database, gets the same error
[screenshot](http://s2.postimg.org/f92ag4iu1/436.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've found the solution.
I went to Server Properties -> Security and changed Server authentication from "Windows Authentication mode" to "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode".
Probably, it would be much easier to find out, what is causing an error, if there was special error  message for this case.

[image]